# Exclude pre-defined resource in apk file

Tags: java, android, ant, gradle, android-studio

Exclude pre-defined resource in apk file

I created a blank project with Android Studio. And then generated apk file, look inside that file I can see : in res/drawable folder there are many unwanted files like : abc_ic_clear_holo_light.xml, abc_ic_clear.xml, and in res/drawable-mdpi-v4 folder there many unwanted images like: abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo.9.png, abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo.9.png.

1. How to remove all of that files ?
2. How to disable creating drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi-v4 (Because, I use webview to display ui of application, so I dont need support multiscreen with android native)

Comment: "How to remove all of that files ?" -- stop using the `AppCompat` action bar backport. At minimum, you have attached its library project to your app. And, if you are inheriting from `ActionBarActivity`, you are actually using those resources.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Mine apk file size was reduced from 1.5MB to 58KB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to remove the referenced libary (seems like you added `android-support-v7` to your project).