# How to reduce the size of an APK file

Tags: android, apk

When I create a new android app using Android Studio and export the APK file, the resulting file is 914kb in size. I did not add any code or resources. How can I bring the size to the bare minimum.

Thanks in advance.

Update: Enabled proguard, that brought down the size to 564kb. I extracted the apk and saw there are so many drawable folders in the apk
[image]

All these folders contains PNG files with names starting with "abc_ic.." . Is there a way to exclude them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can Use `Android ProGuard tool`. The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer.

For more details, please refer [here](http://www.quora.com/How-can-one-reduce-the-size-of-APK-Android-packages).

You can try to remove reference's libary(seem you added android-support-v7 to your project).

Comment: The size was because of android-support-v7 library.This helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204069/exclude-pre-defined-resource-in-apk-file